# Create a nodes graph / horizontal tree view in asp.net - is there any webcontrol out there?

Tags: asp.net, graph

i have a list of nodes that i would like to represent them as a binary tree style nodes graph, where a parent can have 1 or more childs.

I  know that you can get the same functionality if you use the standard treeview control, but from vision perspective, its not good for me. If there is any tree view that do this kind of layout, please let me know.

basically, to do something like that: http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/5020/binarytreemt6.jpg

hence, horizontal tree view!

please let me know if you know about anything helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is not much relevant info on web. May be you'll find useful these links: [Tree Chart Generator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TreeGenerator.aspx) and [Hierarchical Tree](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Hierarchical_Tree.aspx). Otherwise I'm afraid you'll have to implement it by yourself using CSS as advised [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1507470.aspx/1) (unfortunately without details).